# C++ - no match for ‘operator<’

Tags: c++11, stl, operator-overloading, ros, stdmap

I have the following map:

```
std::map<my_msgs::Nodelet, int> mRunningProcPID;
```

When trying to insert a new pair to the map I am getting the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const my_msgs::Nodelet_<std::allocator<void> >’ and ‘const my_msgs::Nodelet_<std::allocator<void> >’)
       { return __x < __y; }
```

I get it that I need to override the < operator for my_msgs::Nodelet, the problem is that I do not have access to that h file since it is being auto generated by ROS.

Any idea what can I do?

Comment: Can't you define a **non-member** `operator<` for `my_msgs::Nodelet` in the same file where you have your map? Also note that `std::map` has a third template parameter for comparator, so it's not necessary to provide a `operator<`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `std::map` will attempt to index the mapped elements, and it doesn't know how to index `my_msgs::Nodelet` because it doesn't know how to compare this object.

You have to provide a third parameter when declaring this map, with a Compare function, or implement the necessary interface (handler for operator `<`) for it to use the default comparison method.

But you can also avoid this trouble by just using `std::unordered_map` instead.

`std::unordered_map` will do pretty much the same thing `std::map` does but it doesn't bother to index the elements. This approach is also considered faster in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

> Any idea what can I do?

#### Option 1: Use a non-member function to compare two `Nodelet` objects.

You can define a non-member function `operator<` between two `Nodelet` objects with the following signature.

```
bool operator<(my_msgs::Nodelet const& lhs, my_msgs::Nodelet const& rhs);
```

You don't need the ability to modify the class to do that. You can declare it in your own .h file and define it in your own .cpp file.

#### Option 2: Use a functor to compare two `Nodelet` objects

You can define a functor with the following interface:

```
struct CompareNodelet
{
    bool operator()(my_msgs::Nodelet const& lhs, my_msgs::Nodelet const& rhs) const;
};
```

and use it to construct the map.

```
std::map<my_msgs::Nodelet, int, CompareNodelet> mRunningProcPID;
```

Comment: When trying to follow path 1, I get the following error:
error: ‘bool my_manager::Launcher::operator<(const Nodelet&, const Nodelet&)’ must take exactly one argument
   bool operator<(const my_msgs::Nodelet &lhs, const my_msgs::Nodelet &rhs);

Comment: @RoboGil, that needs to be a non-member function. Remove the `my_manager::Launcher::` from there.

Comment: oops, right... but once I remove it i get back the previous error:

no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const my_msgs::Nodelet_<std::allocator<void> >’ and ‘const my_msgs::Nodelet_<std::allocator<void> >’)
       { return __x < __y; }

just to be sure, this is my implementation in the same cpp where I try to insert a pair to the map:

bool operator<(my_msgs::Nodelet const &lhs, my_msgs::Nodelet  const &rhs){
    return true;
}

Comment: @RoboGil, you need to put your operator into a `my_msgs` namespace so it can be discovered via [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).